# How to import function to main namespace of my module?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7, and am building a module with a lot of subdirectories. The structure looks something like this:

```
mainmodule/
  __init__.py
  submodule/
    __init__.py
    somefunction.py
    someotherfuntion.py
```

Now when importing i would, rather than having this:

```
>>> from mainmodule.submodule.somefunction import func
>>> func(do_some_stuff)
```

i want this:

```
>>> import mainmodule
>>> mainmodule.func(do_some_stuff)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should then import and expose your function in your mainmodule's `__init__.py`:

```
from .submodule.somefunction import func
```